# Div contents disappears about milliseconds of appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML:

```
<form id='pool_play'>
    <?php           
        $PLAYERS = 8;
        for ($i=1; $i <= $PLAYERS; $i++) { 
            print $i . ' <input type="text" class="initial_players" autofocus> <br/>';
        }
    ?>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="random"> Randomize bracket</button>
</form>
<p class="debug"></p>
```

js:

```
$("#pool_play").submit(function(event) {
    var participants = $('.initial_players').map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();

    for (var i = 0; i < participants.length; i++) {
        $('p.debug').append(participants[i] + " ");
    }
});
```

I'm basically trying to do is that when the form of `#pool_play` is submitted, print the contents of the input boxes in the `.debug` paragraph tag.
What happens is that it appears for a few milliseconds and then disappears. My guess is when the page is submitted, the old data(meaning the content of the `.debug` paragraph after it gets filled) gets thrown away. Tips?

Comment: how your for is submitted ?  , ajax ?

Comment: nope, this is pretty much my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prevent the submit action or the page will just reload without your changes to the page.

```
$("#pool_play").submit(function(event) {
    var participants = $('.initial_players').map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();

    for (var i = 0; i < participants.length; i++) {
        $('p.debug').append(participants[i] + " ");
    }

    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

It may be a better idea however to change your button to a `button` instead of a `submit`

```
<button type="button" class="random"> Randomize bracket</button>
```

Comment: The first one did the trick. However, the second one wouldn't get the submit(function()) to get called;at least that's why I changed it to submit.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the page from submitting using `event.preventDefault()`

```
$("#pool_play").submit(function(event) {
    var participants = $('.initial_players').map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();

    for (var i = 0; i < participants.length; i++) {
        $('p.debug').append(participants[i] + " ");
    }
    event.preventDefault();//stops submit
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at code. You catching `submit` event, getting data printing them... And then you go out from your function, so default action for `submit` event are executed by browser, because you don't stop it. Thats why you see this content only in miliseconds - browser is refreshing page.

You should use [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) function to prevent browser from submiting form after execution your function.